# zlib in Xcode 7.0

Tags: xcode, swift, gzip, nsdata

I try to implement "NSDate+GZIP" in Xcode 7.0 using Swift 2.0. Without success so far because the module "zlib" can not be found (Error: "No such module 'zlib'").

This is what I have tried to do so far:

1. Add libz.tbd to "Link Binary with Libraries" in Build phases > "No such module 'zlib'"
2. Add "-lz" to "Other Linker Flags" in Build Settings > "No such module 'zlib'"
3. - Go to Build Phases > Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other
   - Do "CMD"+Shift+G (Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
   - Adding libz.dylib  > "No such module 'zlib'"

Same error occurs in 7.1 beta. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Your method #1 works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check:

Swift compiler import paths in build settings as here:
[image: build settings]

zlib folder is yellow (added as a group):
[image: folder]

you have libz.tbd in linked fw and libs:
[image: linked fw]

Also try building the project before trying to use the module.

Comment: Building the project without lib works. With zlib it doesn't. Module zlib can still not be loaded. This error is shown: "Error (from SourceKit): 'Could not load module: zlib'".

Comment: What are the contents of module.modulemap and include.h?